# Ruby script with mechanize and nokogiri

Tags: ruby

So basically I asked a question earlier and got an answer which solved that question but I now realise I need more help as I have spent the last few hours trying to fix this but keep getting "nil:Nilclass: error. Basically I need to go through every show listed on this site (so through each letter, and through each page this letter has) and get the following:
 1. The shows title (this part I have done)
 2. then either copy the page url for each show and add "/episodes/" to the end of it, or click the show and then the episode tab and copy that url.

This is what I have so far:

```
require 'mechanize'
shows = Array.new
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get 'http://www.tv.com/shows/sort/a_z/'
agent.page.search('//div[@class="alphabet"]//li[not(contains(@class, "selected"))]/a').each do |letter_link|
  agent.get letter_link[:href]
  agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').each { |show_link| shows << show_link.text }

  while next_page_link = agent.page.at('//div[@class="_pagination"]//a[@class="next"]') do
    agent.get next_page_link[:href]
    agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').each { |show_link| shows << show_link.text }
  end
end

require 'pp'
pp shows
```

So an end result would like something like the following:
Title: Game of Thrones
URL: http://www.tv.com/shows/game-of-thrones/episodes/

I have tried everything (even writing it from scratch) but just can't seem to add the extra parts so I was hoping someone here my be able to help me do so. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
require 'mechanize'
shows = {}
base_uri = "http://www.tv.com/"
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get 'http://www.tv.com/shows/sort/a_z/'
agent.page.search('//div[@class="alphabet"]//li[not(contains(@class, "selected"))]/a').each do |letter_link|
  agent.get letter_link[:href]
  letter = letter_link.text.upcase
  shows[letter] = agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').map{ |show_link| {show_link.text => base_uri << show_link[:href].to_s << 'episodes/'} }

  while next_page_link = agent.page.at('//div[@class="_pagination"]//a[@class="next"]') do
    agent.get next_page_link[:href]
    shows[letter] << agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').map{ |show_link| {show_link.text => base_uri << show_link[:href].to_s << 'episodes/'} }
  end
  shows[letter].flatten!
end
puts shows
```

This will create the following structure `Hash[letter] => Array[{ShowName => LinktoEpisodes}]`

Example:

```
{"A"=>[{"A Show"=>"http://www.tv.com/shows/a-show/episodes/"},{"Another Show"=>"http://www.tv.com/shows/another-show/episodes/"},...],"B"=>[B SHOWS....],....}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! Works great..only problem is that it leaves out the http:// part i.e. `{"Broadway Open House"=>"/shows/broadway-open-house/episodes/"}`. Is there a way to make sure it includes this?

Comment: @HarryLucas edited you just need to add the base_uri in with the string